# Rendering Problems: Failed to load platform rendering library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I've searched Stackoverflow and I can't find a solution to my problem..

When I try to view my "activity_main.xml" or "fragment_main.xml".. I get this error:

> Rendering Problems
>
> Failed to load platform rendering library

On the little green Android Icon that I believe displays the API versions.. I have version 24 and 23.. I changed it to 23 (I tried both) and I'm still getting that error.

When I look at the AVD Manager.. both the "Android Accelerated x86" and "Android ARMv7a" emulator both use API 23 as well.

I'm banging my head on thew all, any help with what's going on?

All the StackOverflow links say to change the version number and that's what I did but still no go..

Comment: In a now-deleted answer, I suggested dropping to API Level 19. The OP installed that, but is still getting the error, even after restarting Android Studio. Usually, API Level 19 has been sufficient for me, so I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: i went as low as the lowest API.. and i also tried remaking a project and started with the API that it was recommending: API 10: Android 2.3.3.  And I made sure to install that API as well but still no go...

Comment: @CommonsWare in your deleted comment.. you said you don't even use the preview?  I'm new to Android but..how can you create a GUI if you can't even see the preview?  maybe I just have to do the same.. thanks

Comment: "how can you create a GUI if you can't even see the preview?" -- there are two sub-tabs on the layout editor, down towards the bottom. One is "Design", where you are encountering your problems. The other is "Text", where you can see the actual XML of the layout resource. I work with the layout XML.